# Split HDFS files into multiple local files using Java

Tags: java, hadoop

I have to copy HDFS files into local file system using Java Code and before writing to the disk split into multiple parts . The files are compressed using snappy / lzo. I have used Bufferedreader and Filewriter to read and write the file . But this operation is very slow . 20 Mins for 30 GB file. I can dump file using hadoop fs -text in 2 minutes (but can not split it). Is there anything else that I can do to speed up the operation ?

Comment: Is the dump, to the screen or to a file?

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had two do pass , first to get the line count and then the Split. hadoop fs -text was cpu intensive. Did the below approach :

1) Use a line count Java program as Map reduce to get the line count in the file. Then dividing it by total number of files I need i got the count of lines to write to each file .

2) Use the code mentioned this link with hadoop fs -text

https://superuser.com/a/485602/220236

Hope it helps someone else.